# Percentile rank (inclusive) in R

Tags: r, percentile

Percentile rank is frequently defined by the following formula:

Percentile rank = (L/N)*100

L=Number of values in dataset lower than or equal to value of interest
N=number of data points

In R, it is common to calculate percentile rank of values in a vector by

```
Percentile_Rank=rank(vec)/length(vec)*100)
```

However, I would like to use a slightly modified definition of percentile rank, which is defined by the same formula as above but

L = Number of values in dataset strictly lower than the value of interest

This is similar to the PERCENTILERANK.EXC function in Excel.

Is there a function built into R to calculate this? Otherwise, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
y = 1:10

# traditional percentile
rank(y)/length(y) * 100
#  [1]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 

# percentile considering those values preceding current value
vapply(y, function(x){
  sum(y < x)/length(y) * 100
}, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1L))
#  [1]  0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

Comment: Yes this seems to solve my problem. Thanks!